# Append to column-string without reading it from Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

how is it possible to append to a column (type string) without reading the whole value from the database.

Let's say the column, named "mycol" contains the string 'TESTtestTEST' and now I want to APPEND to this string the value 'abc', so 'TESTtestTESTabc' is stored in column mycol.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beside the fact you are using EF as DataLayer, wouldn't this task be done with an UPDATE statement? If so, you can execute the remote/store command on the datacontext to either call a stored procedure ( good ) or passing directly the SQL ( not so good ).

Comment: Yes, normally I would do this with an update statement. Is there a way without the overhead of a stored-procedure (and no direct sql)?

Comment: A stored proc has no overhead, who has told you so? and the logic stays in the server, easy to change, search, backup and reuse...

Comment: I am using postgresql, the pgsql language is not compiled, it is interpreted there. Maybe I can only put the raw update statement to the stored procedure and leave all calculation to the application logic. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL I would do:
UPDATE my_table SET mycol=CONCAT(mycol,'abc') WHERE ID=1;